# .htaccess redirect: matching word-word-word

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file contain this:

```
RewriteRule ^((products)/([a-zA-Z-]+)*)$ index.php?page=products&category=$3&level=1
```

it works fine for: word-word (one dash), but it fails for two dash: word-word-word, example:

products/electronics-solid (works here)

products/word-word-word (fails here)

How to solve it?

Comment: What does it do when it *fail*s? Do you want to separate the parts in htaccess or in PHP?

Comment: From my understanding that regex is working perfectly with any amount of dashes, maybe the problem is not in your .htaccess !?

Comment: Why the double capture groups? Why the extra repetition `*` after word parts?

Comment: @mario: I changed that when it failed, I tried to match multiple occurrence of dashes

Comment: @xception: it works perfectly for all cases except (word-word-word)! it fails to redirect

Comment: "It fails" is not a sufficient description. Enable the [RewriteLog and excerpt error/access.log](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108).

Comment: @mario: I solved it, I found the issue: (products) not match for those links that has word-word-word then it fails because there is no word of (products)